# Collection of Class and inheritence

Tags: java, generics, covariance

I would like to have a collection of Class'es of a specific subtype to achieve something like this:

```
public class Test {
    private class Parent {}
    private class Child1 extends Parent{}
    private class Child2 extends Parent{}

    List<Class<Parent>> classes = new ArrayList();

    public Test() {
        classes.add(Child1.class); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();

    }
}
```

How to achieve the above without upsetting the compiler?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use

```
List<Class<? extends Parent>> classes = new ArrayList<>();
```

---

This

```
List<Class<Parent>> classes = new ArrayList();
```

"upsets" the compiler, since it requires the elements of the list to be of type `Class<Parent>`. However `Child1.class` is of type `Class<Child1>`. Note that `Class<Child1>` does **not** extend `Class<Parent>`.

Comment: To improve this answer you can also add explanation of why compiler didn't like previous version (something about generics not being covariant).

Answer (score 4):

Change your list definition to `List<Class<? extends Parent>>` and the compiler should be happy. This would define the list to contain any class that extends `Parent`, i.e. `Parent` and subclasses.

Note that `List<? extends Class<Parent>>` would not work since you can't extend `Class` and even if you could the list might then actually be an `ArrayList<Class<Child1>>` and thus the compiler wouldn't let you add elements to the list.